# Como iniciar dois serviços iguais no TomCat, porém com Final names diferentes

Tags: spring, tomcat, thymeleaf

Basicamente tenho um serviço rodando no Tomcat, eu gostaria de subir uma cópia dele com outro final name no TomCat.

O problema é que existe algum limitador que não é o finalName que me impede de subir dois serviços iguais.

Ao tentar dar 'Start' no serviço o seguinte erro aparece:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/xtr-conteudos-2] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/xtr-conteudos-2]]]
```

A estrutura do projeto compõe Thymeleaf e Spring, porém mesmo buscando este erro não consegui visualizar o que está limitando ele de rodar.

Lembrando que, o serviço que já está aberto funciona normalmente, então não acredito que seja algo de versionamento do JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema deva estar relacionado as portas configuradas do seu Tomcat. Salvo engano, cada aplicativo já vem com o tomcat embutido.

Sendo assim basta você configurar no `application.properties` localizado em `src/main/resources` a respectiva porta a ser utilizada.

Para substituir a porta padrão você precisa utilizar a propriedade `server.port`.

Certifique-se de definir uma porta diferente em cada aplicativo.

Por exemplo, defina server.port=8088 em um aplicativo e server.port=8090 em outro aplicativo, com isto o seu Aplicativo01 será executado na porta `8088` e o seu Aplicativo02 será executado na porta `8090`.

Comment: Irei checar assim que possível, obrigado pela resposta

Comment: infelizmente mesmo subindo um serviço com a porta 8080 e outro com a porta 8090 o mesmo erro continua aparecendo.

Comment: Verifica se existe algo que possa esclarecer melhor no logs/catalina.out